# Struggling to Understand One-to-One and Onto in terms of Rank, Nullity, Null Space, Range, Dimension Theorem for Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

College student here taking Linear Algebra, and I'm struggling to understand One-to-One and Onto in terms of Rank, Nullity, Null Space, Range, Dimension Theorem, and how they all tie in together for a Linear Transformation $T: V \to W.$

When trying to think about how to prove a statement such as "If $\dim(V) = \dim(W),$ then T is one-to-one and onto".

I'm a little lost on what to actually prove in the end. As in, what does it really mean to be one-to-one and onto in terms of Rank, Nullity, Null Space, Range, and the Dimension Theorem?

I'm struggling to understand how these are all integrated together with the concepts of one-to-one and onto transformations. Hopefully someone can break these down into a simple explanation for better understanding. Thank you so much!

Comment: Suggestion:  Questions are easier to follow when one does not present a block of text.  Add some vertical distance between thoughts, ideas.  I'll edit, to suggest an example; you can refine it in an edit if you'd like. Something to keep in mind in further questions you may want to ask.

Comment: My main question is how do I prove a transformation is one-to-one or onto using Rank, Nullity, Null Space, Range, and the Dimension Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

1-to-1 and onto are the same definitions from any other function. Nevertheless, if $T$ is a linear transformation, then the 1-to-1 statement has a really nice interpretation, because $$T(x)=T(y) \implies T(x)-T(y) = 0 \underbrace{\implies}_{T \text{ is linear}} T(x-y)=0$$

Thus, linear functions has this weird property that if $T$ is not 1-to-1 ($x\neq y$ but $T(x)=T(y)$), then there is (at least) a *nonzero vector which is been mapped to zero*

Following this idea naturally leads to define the set of all vectors which are mapped to zero, namely the **Nullspace**, or Kernel. Funny fact is that this Nullspace is indeed a vector subspace from $V$. If you are working over finite-dimensional vector spaces, then it follows that this nullspace has a finite dimension (a.k.a., Nullity)

Last, but not least, since the set of vectors that are mapped to zero is a vector subspace, and we can associate a dimension to it, then the 1-to-1 property has a new interpretation from this p.o.v

> T is 1-to 1 iif $dim(N) = 0$

Which makes sense, because if $T$ is not 1-to-1, we already know that there is a nonzero vector been mapped to zero, which means that the Nullspace has (at least) one linear independent vector (i.e., $dim(N) \neq 0$).

But, on the other hand, if $T$ is 1-to-1, and $x\in N$, then $T(x)=T(0) \underbrace{\implies}_{T\text{ is 1-to-1}} x=0$ which shows that $0$ is the unique element of $N$.

I hope this helps.